How to filter JSON and set fact based on dict comparsion
I am trying to manipulate qualitygate conditions in sonarqube using the API. Unfortunately the sonartools developer made questionable design choices in the past regarding condition management. I am able to create code conditions based on gatename, metric, error and operator, but you are only able to remove those conditions, if you provide the ID that sonarqube creates for your condition.
For that reason, I have to get a list of all conditions, search the metric names and assign the ID accordingly. My second problem is, that some conditions do automatically get a prefix like 'new_' . So I have to also compare sonarqube's prefixed.metrics with my dict metrics.
My vars:
  vars:
    qualitygate:
      - qualitygate_name: Codecover
        operators:
          - metric: coverage
            operator: CT
            error: 1
            state: present
      - qualitygate_name: Conditions_Java
        operators:
          - metric: coverage
            operator: CT
            error: 10
            state: present
          - metric: duplicated_lines
            operator: GT
            error: 5
            state: present
          - metric: reliability_rating
            operator: WT
            error: D
            state: present
          - metric: security_hotspot_reviewed
            operator: CF
            error: D
            state: absent

my tasks:
    - name: Sonarqube | Configuration-QualityGates | Get Condition Details
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: "{{ protocol }}://{{ server_fqdn }}/api/qualitygates/show?name={{ item.qualitygate_name }}"
        user: admin
        password: pass
        method: GET
      register: _result_qgconditions
      loop: "{{ qualitygate }}"
      failed_when: _result_qgconditions.status != 200 and _result_qgconditions.status != 400
    
- name: Sonarqube | Configuration as Code | Qualitygates | Print Conditions with ID
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ _result_qgconditions.results[0].json.conditions }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ qualitygate }}"
        - operators

I managed to filter the JSON response to only list the conditions. But how do I compare the prefix to my metrics and assign the proper id?
ok: [sonarqube.host] => (item=[{'qualitygate_name': 'Codecover'}, {'metric': 'coverage', 'operator': 'CT', 'error': 1, 'state': 'present'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "error": "1",
            "id": "AZOR44V_lbLIR0tr5ThG",
            "metric": "new_maintainability_rating",
            "op": "GT"
        },
        {
            "error": "1",
            "id": "AZOR44WBlbLIR0tr5ThH",
            "metric": "new_reliability_rating",
            "op": "GT"
        },
        {
            "error": "100",
            "id": "AZOR44WDlbLIR0tr5ThI",
            "metric": "new_security_hotspots_reviewed",
            "op": "LT"
        },
        {
            "error": "1",
            "id": "AZOR44WElbLIR0tr5ThJ",
            "metric": "new_security_rating",
            "op": "GT"
        },
        {
            "error": "3",
            "id": "AZOR44WFlbLIR0tr5ThK",
            "metric": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
            "op": "GT"
        }
    ]
}

Not all conditions are created by me. Some are generated by default.
I tried something like that but I don't know how to add the prefix to my var. Of course I could set_fact like var: "new_{{ item[1].metric }}", but I would have to repeat that for every condition I want to manipulate.
- name: Sonarqube | Configuration as Code | Qualitygates | Print Conditions with ID
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ _result_qgconditions.results[0].json.conditions | selectattr('metrics', 'equalto', 'item[1].metric ) }}" 
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ qualitygate }}"
        - operators

Even if I accomplish to compare my metrics, I have to be able to select the ID from that metric in list. Finally I want to remove my conditions based on the "state".

Well lets solve this systematically. Since we need to handle both prefixed and non-prefixed metrics, and then get their IDs for removal, here's a solution that handles all cases:
- name: Sonarqube | Configuration-QualityGates | Create metric mapping
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    metric_variations: "{{ metric_variations | default({}) | combine({
      item[1].metric: [item[1].metric, 'new_' + item[1].metric]
    }) }}"
  loop: "{{ qualitygate | subelements('operators') }}"

- name: Sonarqube | Configuration-QualityGates | Map conditions to IDs
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    condition_ids: "{{ condition_ids | default({}) | combine({
      item[0].qualitygate_name + '_' + item[1].metric: (
        _result_qgconditions.results[idx].json.conditions 
        | selectattr('metric', 'in', metric_variations[item[1].metric])
        | map(attribute='id') 
        | first | default(none)
      )
    }) }}"
  loop: "{{ qualitygate | subelements('operators') }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: idx

- name: Sonarqube | Configuration-QualityGates | Remove conditions marked as absent
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "{{ protocol }}://{{ server_fqdn }}/api/qualitygates/delete_condition"
    user: admin
    password: pass
    method: POST
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body:
      id: "{{ condition_ids[item[0].qualitygate_name + '_' + item[1].metric] }}"
  when: 
    - item[1].state == 'absent'
    - condition_ids[item[0].qualitygate_name + '_' + item[1].metric] is not none
  loop: "{{ qualitygate | subelements('operators') }}"

Here's how it works:

First task creates a mapping of your metrics to their possible variations (with and without 'new_' prefix)

Second task creates a mapping between your conditions (identified by qualitygate_name + metric) and their IDs in SonarQube

Final task removes conditions marked as 'absent'


You can verify the mappings by adding debug tasks:
- name: Debug | Show metric variations
  debug:
    var: metric_variations

- name: Debug | Show condition IDs
  debug:
    var: condition_ids


Thank you very much for your solution. I just came back from holiday and trying to verify your solution. Currently I already stuck at the first task, because item.metrics is undefined. I need time for analyzing, but I think I would have to change it to: item[1].metrics

Sure! I have also edited my solution - lmk if it works. @G4njaWizard
